# Tarefa de spool para o servidor

Tags: oracle, servidor, procedure, job

Boa noite!

Pessoal, atualmente no meu trabalho, eu tenho que gerar vários arquivos .txt para serem exportados para o banco de outra empresa.

Eu rodo isso na mão e isso é um saco, todo dia rodar, esperar pra enviar e tudo mais.

Eu tentei fazer o comando spool da seguinte forma:

```
spool \\10.0.0.1\diretorio\arquivo.txt
select * from schema.tabela_qualquer;
spool off;
```

O arquivo foi gerado nesse servidor, tudo certinho. Seguindo esta mesma linha de raciocínio, de que eu poderia gerar esse arquivo em qualquer computador da rede, eu pensei em fazer um job que fizesse esse serviço pra mim diretamente e o rapaz da outra empresas iria lá e pegava o arquivo.

Porém, se eu teria de fazer:

```
BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.create_job('"exporta_arquivos"',
  job_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  job_action=>'spool \\10.0.0.1\diretorio\arquivo.txt; select * from schema.alguma_tabela; spool off;',
  number_of_arguments=>0,
  start_date=>TRUNC(SYSDATE,'HH'),
  repeat_interval=> 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5',
  end_date=>NULL,
  job_class=>'"DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS"',
  enabled=>FALSE,
  auto_drop=>FALSE,
  comments=> 'Job que faz a exportação de arquivos');
END;
/
```

ou

Se ao invés de

```
job_action=>'spool \\10.0.0.1\diretorio\arquivo.txt; select * from schema.alguma_tabela; spool off;'
```

eu tentar fazer uma procedure e tentar chamar ela pela job_action, acaba me retornando erro de como se eu não pudesse executar o spool por causa das barras '\10.0.0.1' que indicam que vou jogar no servidor.

Teria algum jeito de fazer isso?

Comment: Eu coloquei a job pra executar, o erro gerado é esse:

163934, 11/11/2015 18:27:36, FAILED, 6550, 11/11/2015 18:27:36, 11/11/2015 18:27:36, 0 00:00:00, 1, 1515,16753, 10526, 0 00:00:00.00, "ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 756:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ""\"" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: Nunca fiz isso diretamente, sempre usei mapeamento atraves do `NET USE`, mas pelo seu erro, parece problema de escape de caracter.
Tente assim: `col destino new_value destino
select '\\'||trim(:IP)||'\'||trim(:dir)||'\'||trim(:arquivo) destino from dual;
spool &destino`

Comment: Qual versão do Oracle?

Comment: A versão é Oracle 11g

Comment: tentou o que passei? Tente tambem assim `job_action=>'spool {\\10.0.0.1\diretorio\arquivo.txt}; ... '`

Comment: "ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 756:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ""{"" when expecting one of the following:"

Qualquer jeito que eu tente fazer o spool, dá erro... mesmo se eu colocar ele dentro de uma procedure.

Comment: e assim? `col dest new_value dest    
select '{\\10.0.0.1\diretorio\arquivo.txt}' dest from dual;    
spool &dest`
Testei um código aqui e funcionou exibindo na saida com `prompt "&dest".`

Comment: Voce disse que mesmo que coloque o codigo que funciona em comandos SQL dentro do job_Action ele dá pau? Pelo que entendi, é melhor criar uma procedure pois o corpo do JOB parece não escapar caracteres. Se mesmo assim não der certo, talvez seja necessario definir um PROGRAM que envie o arquivo da saida para o destino.

Comment: Sim, dentro do corpo do job e no corpo da procedure, da function.. ele só funciona em command window no PL/SQL

Comment: Qual o Sistema Operacional onde o Job está sendo executado???

Comment: O sistema é linux

Comment: E o alvo é Windows?

Comment: Sim! Pode ser esse o problema.. mas por que rodando por command window ele deixaria?

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema parece ser apenas de entendimento de como funciona o *sqlplus* e o *job action*.

Quando conectamos a um servidor remoto e executamos alguns comandos, eles estão sendo executados localmente e não remotamente.

Se o servidor estiver em um **Linux no ip 10.1.1.20** e voce estiver em **Windows no ip 10.1.1.113** e tentar enviar um arquivo para outro **Windows no ip 10.1.1.10**, voce o fará como o Windows faz para enxergar computadores na rede, que é usando  ***\\10.1.1.10\diretorio\***.

Agora, quando coloca um JOB diretamete no server onde está o Oracle, ele tem que usar caminhos de rede como um Linux, que não entende nativamente caminhos do tipo *Net Bios*.

Para esse caso vai ser necessário usar o ***smbclient***

Crie uma procedure com as seguintes linhas de comando

```
host mkdir -p ~/tmp
spool ~/tmp/arquivo.txt
select * from schema.tabela_qualquer;
spool off;
host smbclient //10.0.0.1/diretorio -U usuario --pass senha -c "put ~/tmp/arquivo.txt aquivo.txt;"
```

> > NOTA: É necessário que o smbclient esteja instalado